# How do I stop my background music from repeating whenever I press my screen?

Tags: java, android

I am having some trouble with my app because whenever I press the activity  on my phone, the app repeats the music (which overlaps the already existing music). I can't seem to stop this from happening without stopping the music in whole.

Here is the code!

**Main.java:**

```
public class Main extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    music();



}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void music(){
    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.drawable.background_musicmain);
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

}

**XML File:**

```
public class Main extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    music();



}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void music(){
    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.drawable.background_musicmain);
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
}
```

PS: I know there is nothing on the files as of yet, but I am just working on the menu screen for now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you call `MediaPlayer.start();` regardless if the music is already playing. In your method, you can do a simple check to see if the MusicPlayer is already playing, and start it if it's not.

```
public void music(){
    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.drawable.background_musicmain);
    if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to stop the MediaPlayer whenever you are done with playing the music using the following code:

```
player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
         mp.stop();
         mp.release();
    }
 });
```

if you want to continue playing the music, please use a Service to play the music instead of an Activity.